# laravel updateOrCreate query null data

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

try to use eloquent method updateOrCreate() with no success, below is my code

```
$myArray = ['nama_toko' => 'test', 'user_id' => 3];
Store::updateOrCreate(['user_id' => 2], $myArray);
```

it shows error like this :

```
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains 
(22, test, null, 2020-09-20 01:14:30, 2020-09-20 01:14:30). 
(SQL: insert into "stores" ("nama_toko", "updated_at", "created_at") 
values (test, 2020-09-20 01:14:30, 2020-09-20 01:14:30) returning "id")
```

why its not read my array correctly (user_id).
please help and thanks.

this is my stores table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama_toko');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: is `user_id` fillable on that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add user_id to your model as fillable property.

Comment: thanks,, i think need to read more about that mass assignment